# This is a function to delete items from a file.The problems are mentioned as comments

Tags: java

//In this code i don't understand y the item i wish do delete is not being deleted,instead the last line is being deleted,and the item i wish to delete is being printed 2 times.22  is the file size here.

```
static void delete() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter name of item");
    String search=in.next();

    RandomAccessFile file=new RandomAccessFile("a.txt","rw");
    long filesize=file.length();
    file.seek(0);

    long numofrec=filesize/size;

    for(int j=0;j<numofrec;j++){
        String nam= file.readUTF();
        for(int i=0;i<20-nam.length();i++){
            file.readByte();
        }
        if(search.equalsIgnoreCase(nam)){      //the item i wish to delete does not get 
                                               //deleted,instead the last line    
            System.out.printf("%15s    ",nam); //gets deleted,why? How to solve this issue?
            System.out.println();              //i can update an item using same method but can't  delete,why?? 
            file.seek(size*j);
            file.setLength(file.length()-22);
            break;  //if i don't use break,the item i wanna delete gets printed 2 times why??
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Nobody will read them. Most people won't even see them. Mention the problems *as problems*, in text, in your question. In English. Sentences.

Comment: A little effort to make your problem easy to understand and your code easy to read and understand will often translate into prompt great answers. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions.

Comment: What are you trying to get to?

Comment: Your reading code is bizarre. How was this file created? And why are you surprised that the last item gets deleted, when all you're doing is removing the last item from the file, by reducing its length by 22?

Comment: Do not EVER open a file in read and write mode at the same time. Ever. EVER.

Comment: Q with the same method updating is possible but why ain't the pointer seeking right position in case of deletion??

Comment: Also, it is _highly unlikely_ that `.readUTF()` does what you think it does. This method is a death trap. Don't use it. If you want to read files as text, use a `Reader`. If you want to write text, use a `Writer`. And this is 2014, so [use `java.nio.file`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Java7-fs_Wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: opening a file at the same time for reading and writing is a nono.

Unless you really know what you are doing, the basic rule is: **DON'T. DO. THAT**.

What you want to do is:

- opening a temporary file in which you write new contents;
- ensure that the new contents are safely written;
- atomically rename the temporary file to the original file.

Given your code that would be something like this:

```
// Choose appropriate charset; but you SHOULD use UTF-8 in 2014.
final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final CopyOption replace = StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
final CopyOption atomic = StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE;

final Path origin = Paths.get("a.txt").toAbsolutePath();
final Path tmpfile = Files.createTempFile(origin.getParent(), "tmp", "tmp");

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(origin, charset);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newbufferedWriter(tmpfile, charset);
) {
    // manipulate contents: read from the reader, write to the writer
} // CAN FAIL HERE; if it does, DO NOT catch and just printStackTrace()

// finally, rename
try {
    Files.move(tmpfile, origin, replace, atomic);
} catch (AtomicMoveNotSupportedException ignored) {
    Files.move(tmpfile, origin, replace);
}
```